# Partition event log by source

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log

Is there any way to limit the impact of one `source` on a `log` for Windows Event Log?

i.e. most systems report events to the `application` event log.  One system is particularly vocal when there's an issue, logging thousands of errors in a few seconds as it continually retries and fails certain actions, without pausing between attempts.   This means that not only does the offending system's event log only go back a few minutes, but the entire `application` log becomes flooded, losing useful information from other systems on the same server.

I can't do anything about the offending system (short of disabling it), but is there any way to either:

- limit the number of records kept for a single `source`; i.e. so that it can't fill the entire `log`
- move this `source` to a different `log`; so that the app believes it's reporting issues to the same place, but with them now being siloed elsewhere?
- do anything else to protect my logs from this offender?

I've tried simply recreating the source under a different log (see PowerShell below), but with no joy (the new log shows up, but the app seems to be able to continue to report to the old log):

```powershell
Remove-EventLog -Source 'OffendingAppSource'
New-EventLog -Source 'OffendingAppSource' -LogName 'OffendingAppLog'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to limit the impact of one source on a log for Windows Event Log?

I can think of four things you can do to limit the impact:

1. The system is hard-coded to write to this log. This is not going to change without access to the source code. Contact the system creator/vendor to request they write to a custom log only for that application.
2. You can change the frequency of the failure events by creating an event triggered task. Have your task trigger off the event that is flooding the log and run a custom script to stop the service and run some health checks before restarting the service once everything is healthy. This way you have some control over how often the system is logging failure events.
3. Increase the Application log file size and configure the log to auto backup instead of overwrite events.
4. Set up windows event forwarding to an event collector and suppress the events from this application source in the event subscription. This is great for getting all of your server events in one central location for review or ingesting into a SIEM (like Splunk).